# How to find().lean() in Rust mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, rust, rust-rocket

I am trying to make mongodb Document plain in order to apply `okapi`'s open api which does not allow ObjectId in `struct`.

But I found neither building a find option like

`FindOptions::builder().lean().build();`

nor

`colleciton.find(None, None).lean().await?` works.

How do I transform MongoDB `Document` into `JsonSchema`?

[image]

**Example**

Before

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String
}
```

After

```
{
  _id: String,
  name: String
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what type `JsonSchema` is? I couldn't find it in the `okapi` crate that I thought you might be referring to.

Comment: Mongodb `Document` implements `serde::Serialize` so you can use [`serde_json::to_value`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.to_value.html) to get a generic JSON object from it, if that's all you need.

Comment: It should be in `rocket_okapi`. JsonSchema for automatic generation of openapi docs. But ObjectId cannot be used for struct's field.

Comment: `serde_json::to_value` is not what I was looking for. Because It does not make it a  plain struct.

Comment: @HumbleCoder please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom struct using ObjectId as base and the implement JsonSchema for that custom struct

```rs
use mongodb::bson::oid::ObjectId;
use schemars::JsonSchema;
use schemars::schema::Schema;
use schemars::schema::SchemaObject;
use schemars::gen::SchemaGenerator;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ObjectID(ObjectId);

impl JsonSchema for ObjectID {
    fn schema_name() -> String {
        stringify!(String).to_owned()
    }

    fn json_schema(gen: &mut SchemaGenerator) -> Schema {
        let mut schema: SchemaObject = <String>::json_schema(gen).into();
        schema.number().minimum = Some(1.0);
        schema.into()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, JsonSchema)]
pub struct Customer {
    pub _id: ObjectID,
    pub name: String
}

fn main() {
    let c = Customer{_id: ObjectID(ObjectId::new()), name: String::from("John")};
    println!("{:?}", c);
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&c).unwrap();
    println!("serialized = {}", serialized);

    let deserialized: Customer = serde_json::from_str(&serialized).unwrap();
    println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);
}

// Output
// Customer { _id: ObjectID(ObjectId("6210af6079e3adc888bef5af")), name: "John" }
// serialized = {"_id":{"$oid":"6210af6079e3adc888bef5af"},"name":"John"}
// deserialized = Customer { _id: ObjectID(ObjectId("6210af6079e3adc888bef5af")), name: "John" }
```